# Need help counting number of error types for employees

Tags: calculated-column, counter

I have a SharePoint list that captures employee details and the error types they have committed. In the same list, I would like a column to auto-capture the number of instances of each error type when we select from the error type column.  couldn't figure out how. note: :)I am a beginner in SharePoint, our organization doesn't give access to any sort of coding

Comment: Instead of creating a new column, try adding a grouping on your Error type column in list view settings. Check this for more info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-grouping-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-18548b63-a869-4fcf-89b1-ba3d04784df7

Comment: more than the count, i need the instance count for each error type for every employee. .. let me try and give a background here. So if employee 1 makes error type A for 1st time, he gets 1 point , same employee 1 makes error Type B for 1st time, he gets 1 point, and then he repeats error type A, so he gets 5 point. In total he now has 7 points.  similarly each employee will have their points.

Comment: In my list i have a few details along with employee name and error type as a drop down. if i have a instance counter, then based on that i can have a If formula to calculate points

Comment: This is not possible to achieve using just SharePoint OOTB capabilities. You may need to use the custom coding or maybe workflow/Power Automate to do the necessary calculations.

Comment: Also, calculated column will not be able access the column values from different list items.

Comment: any suggestions on how to get this done via microsoft flows?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online?  or another version of SharePoint Server On-premises?